# Remove ALL NTFS ACL's except time stamps - for data migration

Tags: windows, ntfs, acl

I am migrating some data (2TB) off of a Windows NTFS server file share to a Mac OS X file share. I need to strip all the NTFS permissions, except for the time stamps.

Any good scripts out there with example directory names\group\users you can share?

I need a way to do this from Windows or in OS X.

Thx!

Answer (score 3):

[Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) will do everything you are looking for.

Comment: Dammit! Why didn't i think of that. i use it all the time lol! doh!
does it work on a mac though?

Comment: @Mucker - Robocopy will only run on a Windows client, but the target can be an OSX network share.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't NTFS a windows file system and Mac OS has its own file system? I am VERY limited in my Mac knowledge though. I know MACs can read NTFS drives but you are saying you are moving the data to a new share on the Mac. This means you will lose the NTFS security naturally because the Mac server won't have any NTFS drives in it...unless of course you have installed one?

As for time stamps I don't think you can change these...timestamps are timestamps and are there for a reason. usually the main timestamp people want to keep intact is "date modified". Have you even tested this with one file moving it to the Mac? I have just tested it now moving a file between two pc's on NTFS drives and the date modified wwasn't changed. "date created" and "last time accessed" were though. I cant vouch for the same happening on a Mac however as i dont have one!

If the timestamps could be modified then they could be abused.

Comment: Timestamps *can* be modified, using [public APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about it. When copying across file system boundaries NTFS permissions will not be copied.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing is to change ownerships to the Administrators group (**`takeown /r /a somefolder`**) and reset the file permissions with inherited ones (**`icacls somefolder /reset /t /c`**).

However, you shouldn't have to do this, because NTFS-specific data (ownership, ACLs, auditing) will simply be lost when copying to the file system used by Mac OS X.

Comment: isn't that what i already said about the drive permissions??
And taking ownership and changing perms will update the modified date.

So he should use the APi u mentioned to keep the timestamps the same

Comment: @Mucker: The "Modification" timestamp only applies to file *data*, not to metadata. It is not updated when modifying ACLs or attributes.